# Docker copy misses some files

Tags: docker

First I would like to thank you for helping me.
Please be kind as it is my first post here.

I am trying to build a docker container but the COPY step seems not to work properly.

Here is my DockerFile

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install vim tree unzip

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

Here is my directory tree

```
├── Dockerfile
├── events
│   ├── backend      drwxr-xr-x
│   │   ├── stuff    drwxr-xr-x
│   ├── frontend     drwxr-xr-x
│   │   ├── stuff    drwxr-xr-x
```

I am part of the docker group.

The weird thing happening is that stuff from backend is copied but not stuff from frontend.

I remember using COPY this way and it worked.
I might have missed a behavior of COPY.

Thanks for helping me.

Cheers.

Comment: Could you append the permissions? You can get them through the command `ll` in the directory if you're using linux.

Comment: All the files are drwxr-xr-x and I am the owner. I am also part of the docker group.

Comment: How about Dockerfile and events folder, do you see them as well? What's your build context? Are you building with `docker build -t myimage .`?

Answer (score 3):

Did you check if you have `.dockerignore` in your project?

Docker `COPY` will silently ignore all patterns mentioned in `.dockerignore`.